# I am getting error when I am trying to access database on render with node and express.js .( errno: -4077)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I am getting error when I am trying to access database on render postgresql.

I am using node and express.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYA44.png)
*[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BH84c.png)

**[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js index1.js`
Server is running on port:  3000
Error got in API:  Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND dpg-ckdsqhtjhfbs73803ts0-a.oregon-postgres.render.com
at C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\ALL_RELATED_WITH_\testbackapi\todobackapi\node_modules\pg-pool\index.js:45:11
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\ALL_RELATED_WITH_\testbackapi\todobackapi\index1.js:46:20 {
errno: -3008,
code: 'ENOTFOUND',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
hostname: 'dpg-ckdsqhtjhfbs73803ts0-a.oregon-postgres.render.com'***

I am try to resolve this problem and need some help to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're connecting to a render DB from outside of render, try prefixing your hostname with `postgresql://` or `postgres://`.

Depending on how `Pool` parses the host URL, it'll need the correct protocol defined.

EDIT: Pool is very particular about how each part of the url is defined. Here's an example configuration for connecting to render:

```
const pool = new Pool({
   host: "dpg-ckdsqhtjhfbs73803ts0-a.oregon-postgres.render.com",
   ssl: true,
   port: 5432
   user: "mydb_avgf_user",
   database: "mydb_avgf",
   password: "PASSWORD"
});
```

Comment: I used hostname with url in again test.** but It got an error Error **. My git repo url is

Comment: ITH_\testbackapi\todobackapi\index1.js:28:20 {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'postgres://dpg-ckdsqhtjhfbs73803ts0-a.oregon-postgres.render.com'

Comment: git url https://github.com/Tejasshri/myBackendAppWithPostgre.git

Comment: Got it working. Pool is very particular about how you specify each part of the connection string. For me the problem was SSL (render needs it):


const pool = new Pool({
  host: "dpg-ckdsqhtjhfbs73803ts0-a.oregon-postgres.render.com",
  ssl: true,
  port: 5432,
  user: "mydb_avgf_user",
  database: "mydb_avgf",
  password: "PASSWORD",
});


Or you can use the connectionString approach:

const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString: 'postgres://mydb_avgf_user:PASSWORD@dpg-ckdsqhtjhfbs73803ts0-a.oregon-postgres.render.com:5432/mydb_avgf?ssl=true'
});

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir I was in trouble for 2 weeks................